# Datatable VS dataview

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Hy ,
I really don't understand the difference between datatable and dataview since we can do :

```
   Dim dtb As New DataTable()
   Dim dtv As DataView = dtb.DefaultView
```

thanks in advance .