# .net - Sorting a Data Table

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting

How to sort datatable using VB.NET? I've already read this thread but I having the same output. 
[Sorting a Data Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472913/sorting-a-data-table)
[How do I sort a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505979/how-do-i-sort-a-datatable)

Also, I've tried the sample in Microsoft but still it's not sorting.

```
        Dim locationTable As New DataTable("Location")
    ' Add two columns
    locationTable.Columns.Add("State")
    locationTable.Columns.Add("ZipCode")

    ' Add data 
    locationTable.Rows.Add("Washington", "1")
    locationTable.Rows.Add("California", "2")
    locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", "3")
    locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", "4")
    locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", "5")
    locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", "6")
    locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", "7")
    locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", "8")
    locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", "9")
    locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", "10")
    locationTable.AcceptChanges()

    Console.WriteLine("Rows in original order" & vbLf & " State " & vbTab & vbTab & " ZipCode")
    For Each row As DataRow In locationTable.Rows
        Console.WriteLine(" {0} " & vbTab & " {1}", row("State"), row("ZipCode"))
    Next

    ' Create DataView 
    Dim view As New DataView(locationTable)

    ' Sort by State and ZipCode column in descending order
    view.Sort = "ZipCode ASC"

    Console.WriteLine(vbLf & "Rows in sorted order" & vbLf & " State " & vbTab & vbTab & " ZipCode")
    For Each row As DataRowView In view
        Console.WriteLine(" {0} " & vbTab & " {1}", row("State"), row("ZipCode"))
    Next
```

The output is 
Rows in sorted order

State       ZipCode

Washington      1

Hawaii      10

California      2

Hawaii      3

Hawaii      4

Hawaii      5

Hawaii      6

Hawaii      7

Hawaii      8

Hawaii      9

It should be 1 ~ 10 right? :(

Comment: No, your column is a string not a number, the rules are different in this context

Comment: You could also write a linq query that sets the result in the right order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Zipcode Column considered as **String**, so you need to specify Coumn DataType as **Int**

Try this

```
Dim locationTable As New DataTable("Location")
' Add two columns
locationTable.Columns.Add("State",Type.GetType("System.string"))
locationTable.Columns.Add("ZipCode",Type.GetType("System.int32"))
' Add data 
locationTable.Rows.Add("Washington", 1)
locationTable.Rows.Add("California", 2)
locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", 3)
locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", 4)
locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", 5)
locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", 6)
locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", 7)
locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", 8)
locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", 9)
locationTable.Rows.Add("Hawaii", 10)
locationTable.AcceptChanges()

Console.WriteLine("Rows in original order" & vbLf & " State " & vbTab & vbTab & " ZipCode")
For Each row As DataRow In locationTable.Rows
    Console.WriteLine(" {0} " & vbTab & " {1}", row("State"), row("ZipCode"))
Next

' Create DataView 
Dim view As New DataView(locationTable)

' Sort by State and ZipCode column in descending order
view.Sort = "ZipCode ASC"

Console.WriteLine(vbLf & "Rows in sorted order" & vbLf & " State " & vbTab & vbTab & " ZipCode")
For Each row As DataRowView In view
    Console.WriteLine(" {0} " & vbTab & " {1}", row("State"), row("ZipCode"))
Next
```

f you use Dataset...Check like this

```
If Dataset IsNot Nothing AmdAlso DataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count>0
 // Your Code Here
End IF
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I used DataSet? Please see this link. http://pastebin.com/Sc3bXTW7 I'm sorry, I don't know how to post the code here.

Comment: If you use Dataset...Check like this `If Dataset IsNot Nothing AmdAlso DataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count>0 Then

Answer (score 0):

I think it it works - the ZIP codes are sorted as **strings**. If you want to sort as numbers, set the type of the `Zip` column:

```
locationTable.Columns.Add("ZipCode", typeof(int)) // sorry, I'm a C# guy
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that order is because the zip code's data type is mentioned as a string. So between "1" and "10", "1" comes before "10", and between "2" and "10", "2" comes after "10".

It's like first you get the character '1' so thats placed first. Then the character '1' is found again in the list which is immediately followed by '0' in the row having zipcode 10. So that's placed immediately after the row with zipcode '1'. Then it puts the row with zipcode 2 after 10. Remember they are strings here and not numbers.

You only need to change the type of zipcode column to integer.

Answer (score 0):

What I did it to add new column. And get the old value and save it to the new column

```
oDetail.Columns.Add("new_line", GetType(Integer))
                    Dim i As Integer = 1
                    For Each row In oDetail.Rows
                        row("new_line") = i

                        i += 1
                    Next
                    oDetail.DefaultView.Sort = "new_line DESC"
```